# Не качается шаблон Vue-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, vue-cli

При попытке инита вуе кли :

```
vue init webpack app1

? Target directory exists. Continue? Yes
   vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 13204:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:252:
```

При том что все пакеты нормально качаются и устанавливаются то есть с настройками прокси все впорядке

.npmrc

```
proxy=http://...:9999/

http-proxy=http://...:9999/

https-proxy=http://...:9999/

npm_config_strict_ssl=false

strict-ssl=false

ca = null


registry=http://registry.npm.taobao.org
disturl=https://npm.taobao.org/dist
chromedriver-cdnurl=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver
couchbase-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/couchbase/v{version}
debug-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-inspector
electron-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/
flow-bin-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/flow/v
fse-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/fsevents
fuse-bindings-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/fuse-bindings/v{version}
git4win-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/git-for-windows
gl-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/gl/v{version}
grpc-node-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors
hackrf-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/hackrf/v{version}
leveldown-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/leveldown/v{version}
leveldown-hyper-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/leveldown-hyper/v{version}
mknod-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/mknod/v{version}
node-sqlite3-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors
node-tk5-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-tk5/v{version}
nodegit-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/nodegit/v{version}/
operadriver-cdnurl=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/operadriver
phantomjs-cdnurl=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/phantomjs
profiler-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-inspector/
puppeteer-download-host=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors
python-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/python
rabin-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/rabin/v{version}
sass-binary-site=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass
sodium-prebuilt-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/sodium-prebuilt/v{version}
sqlite3-binary-site=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/sqlite3
utf-8-validate-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/utf-8-validate/v{version}
utp-native-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/utp-native/v{version}
zmq-prebuilt-binary-host-mirror=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/zmq-prebuilt/v{version}
```

то ли есть какие-то лимиты в локальной сетке на это дело, но почему тогда качание из репов нормально происходит?

Comment: Какая версия vue-cli?

Comment: C:\Users\is6850>npm -v vue-cli
6.6.0

Comment: vue --version вот так надо

Comment: версия самого вуя - 3.8.3

Comment: а `vue create appName` не работает тоже?

Comment: такое как раз работает

Comment: Есть опция такая - vue  init --offline   . А где этот кеш лежит? Я нашел https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple положить бы в этот кэш